# Overriding an iOS framework symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, mach-o

One of the third-party binary libraries I'm using has an unfortunate `NSLog` statement that I'd like to avoid at runtime (it leaks personal information). The framework developer is unwilling to change this line and I have no alternatives (binary patching is not an option, nor switching providers).

Is it possible to define my own `NSLog` symbol that I could use to filter out the unwanted logging and delegate other logging calls to the original NSLog? Would Apple reject an app that overrides core framework symbols?

Comment: Yes it's possible, just use the same definition as the system one. Since NSLog is a variadic function (accepting varying number of args) you'll probably need something like NSLogv in your overriding implementation. Is the framework a dylib or a static library linked with your app binary? Overriding NSLog will work in the latter case only. As a last resort you could totally silence NSLog http://stackoverflow.com/a/12611692/5329717

Comment: @Kamil.S why only a comment? Just add a little more information, preferably a code sample and this looks like a great answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. You can put this code in any of your .m files, but I recommend AppDelegate.

```
// Objective-C code
void NSLog(NSString *format, ...) {

    //You'll probably want some logic here to determine the issuer of NSLog
    //and silence it(aka return) if necessary

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    NSLogv(format, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

Overriding NSLog will only work if the framework is not a dylib. As a last resort you could totally silence NSLog by redirecting stderr [stackoverflow.com/a/12611692/5329717](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12611692/5329717)